# How to delete a FormData Object

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, drag-and-drop, multipartform-data

Basically what I am trying to do is submit a drag and drop formdata object through an Ajax call. However if I drag and drop a file, then press submit. Then drag and drop ANOTHER file, the old formdata object still exists and attempts to get passed. I get an error in the console (right now its a 403 error because I delete the CSRF token, which I am aware of because I delete everything in the formdata because I didnt want extra things passed to the back end, Id rather just pass an empty formData. So I am unsure why the old form data exists after I press submit. But everytime I drag a new file over more form datas accumulate and of course I get more errors. So my question is, how do I get rid of the formdata once it is submitted and create a new one on file drag and drop. I do not want multiple files to be passed either which is also currently possible (I think do to the same issue that im having)

If any additional help is needed please let me know.

Javascript:

```
(function() {
var dragFile;
// getElementById
function $id(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}


// output information
function Output(msg) {
    var m = $id("messages");
    m.innerHTML = msg + m.innerHTML;
}


// file drag hover
function FileDragHover(e) {

    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    e.target.className = (e.type == "dragover" ? "hover" : "");
}


// file selection
function FileSelectHandler(e) {

    // cancel event and hover styling
    FileDragHover(e);

    // fetch FileList object
    var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;

    formBuilder(files);
    // process all File objects
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
        ParseFile(f);
    }

}
function formBuilder(files) {
    console.log("in form builder!");



    dragFile.set("file", files[0]);

    var submitbutton = $id("submit");

    //submitbutton.addEventListener("click", , false);

    document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function(){
        formuploading(dragFile);
        dragFile.delete("file", files[0]);
        dragFile.delete("from");
        dragFile.delete("MAX_FILE_SIZE");
        dragFile.delete("to");
        dragFile.delete("_csrf");

        delete dragFile;
    });

}

// output file information
function ParseFile(file) {

    Output(
        "<p>File information: <strong>" + file.name +
        "</strong> type: <strong>" + file.type +
        "</strong> size: <strong>" + file.size +
        "</strong> bytes</p>"
    );

}


// initialize
function Init() {

    var fileselect = $id("fileselect"),
        filedrag = $id("filedrag"),
        submitbutton = $id("submitbutton");

    var form = document.getElementById("upload");
    console.log("in initialize");
    dragFile = new FormData(form);

    // file select

    // is XHR2 available?
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    console.log(xhr);
    if (xhr.upload) {

        // file drop
        filedrag.addEventListener("dragover", FileDragHover, false);
        filedrag.addEventListener("dragleave", FileDragHover, false);
        filedrag.addEventListener("drop", FileSelectHandler, false);
        filedrag.style.display = "block";

        submitbutton.style.display = "inline-block";
    }

}

// call initialization file
if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
    Init();
}

function formuploading(formData) {


    console.log("in form uploading");

 // Display the key/value pairs
    for (var [key, value] of formData.entries()) { 
          console.log(key, value);
        }

   // console.log(document.getElementById(("form#upload")));
    $.ajax({
        url: "/upload",
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        success: function (data) {
            document.getElementById("fileselect").value = "";
            //location.reload();
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });

}

$("form#upload").submit(function(e) { 

    document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML = "";

    e.preventDefault();    


    //do IF block to check if there is formdata being passed? or if the value of the input select field is empty. 
    if (document.getElementById("fileselect").value != ""){

        var formData = new FormData(this);
        formuploading(formData);

    }else{
        console.log("file select is empty :)");
        return false;
    }
});

})();
```

Comment: Are you attempting to send the AJAX on file drop or button click?

Comment: on button click, after the drag and drop is completed of course.